Allow Users to Override Default Values in a Vue 3 Component Library
I'm developing a Vue 3 component library and want to allow users to override default values for components. Here's how users would install the library:
// Import styles and library
import { mountLibrary } from '@my/components-library'
import '@my/components-library/style.css'

const componentLibrary = mountLibrary({
  /* Add your configuration here */
})

createApp(App).use(componentLibrary).mount('#app')

I want users to be able to override the default values for a component like this:
const componentLibrary = mountLibrary({
  defaultValues: {
    toastNotification: {
      position: "bottom-right"
    }
  }
})

createApp(App).use(componentLibrary).mount('#app')

Currently, I define my props using the Composition API like this:
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<ToastNotificationProps>(), {
  position: 'bottom-right'
  // ...
})

How can I implement a feature that allows users to override these default values when they configure the component library? What changes do I need to make to support this functionality?

This requires to compute prop values instead of relying on default values in prop definitions. It could be seen the other way, global options could be overridden with props.
The library plugin would provide global options:
const createMyPlugin = ({ defaultOptions } = {}) => (app) => {
  const globalOptions = deepMerge({ toastNotification: ... }, defaultOptions);
  app.provide('my-library-options', globalOptions);
}

And it's more efficient to compute options separately for each prop:
const props = defineProps<ToastNotificationProps>();
const globalOptions = inject('my-library-options');
const position = computed(() => props.position ?? globalOptions.toastNotification.position);


How would you handle a case where the user explicitly wants to provide undefined as a prop?

This is the case for null, there's a semantic difference between those two in JS. undefined means "no provided value", and in a lot of cases there's no way to tell if undefined was provided or a value was omitted, including the case with props. null means "empty value". Would be props.position !== undefined ? props.position : ...

This will be irrelevant in most cases anyway, but it was still a curiosity I had. I think this is the important part: 'In a lot of cases there's no way to tell if undefined was provided or a value was omitted.' This clarified it once and for all, thanks.
